# DESede (3DES) Encryption in RAILO CFML

Tags: .net, encryption, coldfusion, railo, 3des

I've been trying for many days to try and solve this issue.

A 3rd Party webservice requires me to send encrypted data using 3DES with ECB
and PKCS7padding - They're using .NET

The encrypt function within railo CFML is limited to DESede without any further options (i.e. defaults are used for cipher mode and padding).

Has anyone had this issue in Railo and come up with a solution (java based perhaps)? - I'm seriously pulling my hair out here!

Based on Leigh's suggestions below I made some changes:

I've made a bit of progress, I think this key has some kind of MD5 hashing on it.

I fished around the web and modified your solution a bit - I don't think the padding is necessary but the resultant encrypted string at first appears to be what I should expect but then closer on inspection it's incorrect:

```
IvParameterSpec = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec");
Cipher = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Cipher");
SecretKeySpec = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec");
BASE64Decoder = createObject("java", "sun.misc.BASE64Decoder");
Str = createObject("java", "java.lang.String");
MessageDigest = createObject("java", "java.security.MessageDigest");

input  = "<xml><PanNumber>6280390027626871</PanNumber><Req_Currency_Code>826</Req_Currency_Code><Card_Pin>1234</Card_Pin><Till_Amount></Till_Amount><Auth_Code></Auth_Code></xml>";
key = "06098140901984F95E139F29B479D952CB6545C177D21456";

md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, key.length());
keyBytes = md.digest();
newKey = tobase64(keyBytes);
keyBytes2  = binaryDecode(newKey, "base64");
keyBytes2  = arrayMerge(keyBytes, arraySlice(keyBytes, 1, 8));
allnewKey = binaryEncode(javacast("byte[]", keyBytes2), "base64");

encrypted = encrypt(input, allnewKey, "desede", "base64");
WriteDump("encrypted (CF): "& encrypted);`
```

The result is: **26sfwv2DHDj7EHYd5Qao8veDtPbKIcv8rDVhbLPDEaWHO27EUGRF6KrdbXe7NBUVADYMdGuagfO4Tev584dUcgKGJ2h6kWPZxooNUGMgL2xB7e00YOkLosA8wFD569sZUd1MGKuF9yCjY1zCsAE4SgohkcuK9YZ7BizQma99/W9yOsIjAfHtAqGiep4tMTQ+eFASYtPybccsgi8H4brIB/HAu0kaDSAw**

The expected result is:
**26sfwv2DHDj7EHYd5Qao8veDtPbKIcv8rDVhbLPDEaWHO27EUGRF6MxaAzUpJDqQBq8NGgdqmtn6q/wVQNHGWrOE8+aetKVC78nszS3ZO8AHjwoT1igv4lGl78n8jCHHU+KwnBT7KfXIYMTCuwO/MohIiFbGyhMXPsvv3/G4OY1C2nEkN0LweLh4mTgtU8syT1M9XdmvwhaltsmPoFtoE9FujvQpJCY3**

Comment: (Edit) Can you post a sample key and the results you are getting in Railo and .net? I think Railo just uses the java defaults, which are `ECB` and `PKCS5Padding` (mostly compatible with PKCS7padding for 8 bytes). So in theory it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The encrypt function within railo CFML is limited to DESede without
>   any further options (i.e. defaults are used for cipher mode and
>   padding).

Yes, I believe it uses java's defaults ie `DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding` which are compatible with `TripleDES/ECB/PKCS7padding` in .NET. So it should work right out of the box as long as you are using a 24 byte key.

Without knowing more, I am guessing it might be a problem with your key size. .NET supports both 16 and 24 byte keys, but java only supports 24 byte keys. So if your key is only 16 bytes, you need to pad it with the first eight (8) bytes to make it acceptable to Java/Railo.

**CF/Railo Code**

```
<cfscript>
    input  = "DESede (3DES) Encryption in RAILO CFML";
    key    = "ru8femXhTm9jwdGdhb/4Sw==";

    // pad the key with the first eight bytes. then convert back to base64
    keyBytes  = binaryDecode(key, "base64");
    keyBytes  = arrayMerge(keyBytes, arraySlice(keyBytes, 1, 8));
    newKey = binaryEncode(javacast("byte[]", keyBytes), "base64");

    encrypted = encrypt(input, newKey, "desede", "base64");
    WriteDump("encrypted (CF): "& encrypted);
</cfscript>
```

**C# Code**

```
byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("DESede (3DES) Encryption in RAILO CFML");
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("ru8femXhTm9jwdGdhb/4Sw==");

TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider algorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
algorithm.BlockSize = 64;
algorithm.KeySize = 128; // 16 byte key
algorithm.Key = key;
ICryptoTransform cipher = algorithm.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] encrypted = cipher.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
Console.WriteLine("encrypted (.NET): {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
```

**Results:**

```
encrypted (CF):   fMPlk0ZqHDwp2zzZs/Cng7Y6r8Acr55UPJYWJTruEesxkBApsEFo6w==
encrypted (.NET): fMPlk0ZqHDwp2zzZs/Cng7Y6r8Acr55UPJYWJTruEesxkBApsEFo6w==
```

---

**Update:**  Weird. When I MD5 hash the key in .NET I get your first result rather than the "expected result"

```
    String rawInput = "<xml><PanNumber>6280390027626871</PanNumber><Req_Currency_Code>826</Req_Currency_Code><Card_Pin>1234</Card_Pin><Till_Amount></Till_Amount><Auth_Code></Auth_Code></xml>";
    String rawKey = "06098140901984F95E139F29B479D952CB6545C177D21456";
    byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawInput);
    byte[] key = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawKey));
    // ... rest of code
```

**Result:**

```
encrypted (.NET): 26sfwv2DHDj7EHYd5Qao8veDtPbKIcv8rDVhbLPDEaWHO27EUGRF6KrdbXe7NB
UVADYMdGuagfO4Tev584dUcgKGJ2h6kWPZxooNUGMgL2xB7e00YOkLosA8wFD569sZUd1MGKuF9yCjY1
zCsAE4SgohkcuK9YZ7BizQma99/W9yOsIjAfHtAqGiep4tMTQ+eFASYtPybccsgi8H4brIB/HAu0kaDS
Aw
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh - the key I've been sent for testing is this if this helps, I think it's meant to be 24 byte: 06098140901984F95E139F29B479D952CB6545C177D21456

Comment: and the only way I can get a result from this (albeit one that doesn't match the C# result) is if I transform the key using the following function:

**`newKey=toBase64(binarydecode("06098140901984F95E139F29B479D952CB6545C177D21456","hex"))`**

Comment: I've made a bit of progress, I think this key has some kind of MD5 hashing on it.

Comment: modified orig question above.

Comment: (Sorry for the delayed response. I was busy all day.) What were the exact instructions you were given about how to encrypt the string? Did they actually mention hashing?

Comment: I tried it in .NET (MD5 hashing the key first) and got the "Railo" result, not the "expected result". See my updated response.

Comment: Thanks again Leigh. What result did you get in .NET without the hashing? I'll have to speak to 3rd party today to ask about the hashing. They told me the key was 24 bytes but I can't get it to play without manipulating it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Leigh I think I've fixed this now. With your padding and the hashing it now appears to give the desired result.